# Swift 4: Ambiguous Expression in reduce and generics

Tags: swift4

While I was experimenting with generics, I tried to create a function that checks if all elements of a container are the same.

```
 func allItemsMatch<C1: Container, C2: Container>(_ s: C1, _ t: C2) -> Bool 
      where C1.Item == C2.Item, C1.Item: Equatable, C1: Sequence, C2: Sequence { 
     if s.count != t.count { 
         return false 
     } 
     return zip(s, t).reduce(true) { eq, tup in 
         eq && (tup.0 == tup.1) 
     } 
 }
```

The container's protocol definition goes as follows:

```
 protocol Container { 
    associatedtype Item 
    func append(_ item: Item) 
    var count: Int { get } 
 }
```

When I try to compile this I get the following error.

error: expression type 'Bool' is ambiguous without more context

Comment: What's your definition of `Container`? AFAIK, it's not in the standard library.

Comment: Done. See changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it to work by telling the compiler that the sequence elements (which is what ends up in the `Zip2Sequence`) also conform to `Equatable`:

```
func allItemsMatch<C1, C2>(_ s: C1, _ t: C2) -> Bool
  where C1: Container, C2: Container, 
        C1.Item: Equatable, C1.Element: Equatable, 
        C1.Element == C2.Element, C1.Item == C2.Item, 
        C1: Sequence, C2: Sequence {
    if s.count != t.count {
        return false
    }

    return zip(s, t).reduce(true) { eq, tuple in
        eq && (tuple.0 == tuple.1)
    }
}
```

Comment: Is Element in the standard library? Otherwise how did you manage to access it.

Furthermore, I don't see how element is relevant here since I am comparing directly the Items of each container.

Comment: Yes, `Element` is defined in `Sequence`. I believe it's necessary to specify it here because `zip` creates a `Zip2Sequence<C1, C2>` where each tuple has type `C1.Element` and `C2.Element`, respectively.